# 500 HTTP Exception in Flask, whilst trying to read a file through app.open_resource()

Tags: python, flask

Pretty much the title. I tried the code on my local computer and it was fine but when in deployment (Phusion Passenger) this doesn't seem to work.

```
from flask import Flask
import flask
import json
import os

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/mods')
def mods_index():
    try:
        reader = app.open_resource(os.path.join(app.root_path , 'static', 'data', 'modifications.json'))
        modifications = json.load(reader)
        reader.close()
    except:
        flask.abort(500)
    return flask.render_template('mods_index.html', mods=modifications)
```

Comment: Adding specific error handlers(like for `IOError` for example) would help greatly yo understand the issue, as would using something like `traceback.print_exc()`. That said, your error is probably the software not being able to find the JSON file.

Comment: something in your try/except is erroring, thus your except is running instead of the try, and flask aborts with a 500 code because you told it to. Try using debugging features of your ide, or if desperate print things to stdout (or a text file) to figure out whats causing your except to fire off instead of your try.

Comment: Remove the try-except and set `app.debug = True`. As it is this app is not debuggable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a **file path issue**, specifically this line: `reader = app.open_resource(os.path.join(app.root_path , 'static', 'data', 'modifications.json'))` doesn't look correct.

According to Flask's [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.open_resource): `app.open_resource(...)` "*Opens a resource from the application’s resource folder*". In your *code you're specifying the application's root path* twice:

1. First with `app.open_resource(....)`
2. Then again with: `app.root_path`

So your server is attempting to open your `modifications.json` file from: `<app_root_path>/<app_root_path/static/data/modifications.json` as opposed to `<app_root_path>/static/data/modifications.json` where `<app_root_path>` is your application's root directory. So the solution is to get rid of one of those double `<app_root>` mentions. Maybe you could try the following:

```
reader_path = os.path.join('static', 'data', 'modifications.json'))
with app.open_resource(reader_path) as f:
    contents = f.read()
     # do_something_with(contents)
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! It did work in the end, I was getting so mad over this that I didn't realize it was just a path issue.

Comment: Np glad I was able to help!